# how to create push notification channel in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

HttpNotificationChannel class is running in windows phone 8.0 but it is not running in windows phone 8.1 why .

Is there any alternative for windows phone 8.1?

Comment: Provide a code example, so we can replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709907.aspx)

```
PushNotificationChannel channel = null;

try
{
    channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine("Channel :: " + channel.Uri.ToString());

}

catch (Exception ex)
{ 
    // ... 
}
```